# How to get the "key" in ENV variable in perl script

Tags: perl

I am a new user of perl script. I am trying to modify a script to get my required output data. However, I am not sure how to make changes in below statements related to environmental variables:

```
$cmiss_root=$ENV{CMISS_EXECUTABLE};
$cmgui_root=$ENV{CMGUI_2_6_2};
$root=$ENV{ROOT};
```

I think the key between {  } showed the location of those files. So, if I like to change those keys between {  }, how can I get them? My apology for ignorant question as I am a bit confused how to construct a statement with $ENV. Thanks.

Comment: Those statement assign the value of environment variables to Perl variables (for use in the program).

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. Are you asking how to set the environment variables?

Comment: Confusing as @ikegami says. To get, `my $thing = $ENV{VARIABLE};` to set, `$ENV{VARIABLE} = 'thing';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to find out what environment variables there are

```
my @names_of_enviroment_vars = keys %ENV;
```

Will tell you.  If you wish to change the value of an environmental variable you can set it by useing.

```
$ENV{ROOT} = '/new/value/for/root/';
```

Not setting environmental variables like this will only effect this particular Perl script and any executable that the Perl script launches.

Answer (score 0):

hi sorry for making you guys confused, as I was also confused before. What I would like to ask was how I can know environmental variables that I have in my PC. Now I use below code and it seems solved;

```
foreach $key (sort (keys %ENV)) {
    print "$key =$ENV {$key} <br>\n";
}
```